# How to integrate Apache Camel into a Java Spring 3.0 web application to import data

Tags: java, spring-mvc, apache-camel, spring-3

I'm developing a web application based on the Spring 3.0 framework.

No I want to integrate Apache Camel to import data via CSV files into the database. I managed to run Camel and doing the import in the database following the [Apache Camel Spring Configuration example](http://camel.apache.org/spring-java-config-example.html).

But now I want to integrate Camel into the web application so it starts up together. But I'm not sure how to do this. At the moment it seems as if Camel is started beside the web application and uses it's own context. Especially it seems to be started before the web application as the an exception is thrown when Camel tries to auto wire a database repository which is part of the web application.

```
10:57:36.730 [main] ERROR o.s.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'routeConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.GraphRepository com.isarsoftware.ysura.config.RouteConfiguration.graphRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository' defined in class path resource [com/isarsoftware/ysura/config/GraphDBConfig.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.GraphRepository com.isarsoftware.ysura.config.GraphDBConfig.userRepository()] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: ApplicationEventMulticaster not initialized - call 'refresh' before multicasting events via the context: Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Fri Nov 16 10:57:35 CET 2012]; root of context hierarchy
```

I must admit that I'm far away from being a Spring pro. But till now I managed to get everything working by reading blogs and tutorial. But for this problem I couldn't find any guidance yet.

Can anyone suggest me a tutorial or example on who to solve my problem?

Comment: can you post snippets from your web.xml, spring servlet context and your camel context so I can see how you are configuring everything?

Comment: Also include a snippet from GraphDBConfig.userRepository() since that is the method that threw the exception

Answer (score 2):

see http://camel.apache.org/tutorial-on-using-camel-in-a-web-application.html

basically, just add spring listener to your web.xml file

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

then, create a /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml file with your CamelContext

```
<beans...>
    <camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
        <route>
          <from uri="seda:foo"/>
          <to uri="mock:results"/>
        </route>
    </camelContext>
</beans>
```

Comment: Ok, is it possible, to use a @Configuration annotation instead of the XML file? How would I then define a route? That's why I tried to follow the example I mentioned in my question.

Comment: what is seda:foo ?